# CEL comes on when using fuel with ethanol

Tags: ford, cel, gasoline, ethanol

I have 3 Ford vehicles: a 2001 Taurus, a 2006 Taurus, and a 2008 Explorer. All of them have V6 engines. The check engine light for all 3 comes on at times.

If I use gasoline without ethanol, the CEL usually turns off within the first tank. But, **when I switch back to gasoline with 10% ethanol, the CEL eventually comes back on.**

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Have you ran a scan to see what codes are present?

Comment: As @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 says the answer or at least a good clue will lie in the codes that go with the CEL. Without them we're guessing, educated guesses perhaps but still guesses.

Comment: Does the brand of fuel with ethanol matter? How long does it take for the CEL to come back on when you start using ethanol again?

Comment: This is much more likely to be an evap. system code that goes away with a full tank.

Comment: i'd say it would be a rich code what's the engine vin code? u?